# New Registrations on a Wordpress website that has no place to register as a subscriber

Tags: wordpress

I have implemented a simple 5 page basic website in wordpress and clearly though it has a contact form it has no place from where a user can register as a subscriber.

However, over the past month I have been receiving mails regularly that a new user has registered on your website. I suspect this to be some sort of BOT activity as the number keeps on rising every day.

1. How a user can register even if there is no place/form on website wherein he can do so?
2. What advantage does it have for him?
3. How can I keep a check on this?

Comment: Visit `example.com/wp-signup.php`, what shows up?

Answer (score 0):

1. How an user can register even if there is no place/form on website wherein he can do so?

   **Answer**: Even if you have no form for registration, user can register by your `wp-login.php`  page.For example, your admin login have registration link. You can turn on/off user registration from by admin panel. Go `Settings->general` and uncheck `Membership` option any one can register.
2. What advantage does it have for him?

   **Answer**: Most probably the role for new register user as subscriber for your website
3. How can I keep a check on this?

   **Answer**: Go `Settings->general` and uncheck `Membership` option any one can register.

Comment: Most probably the role for new register user as subscriber for your website - I suppose this is good for my website?